# How to match a fingerprint and retrieve data from the database? In simpler way

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Digital Persona 4500 Fingerprint Scanner for my project. I used U.are.U SDK 2.3 for Windows as the SDK and I am able to insert the serialized fingerprint minutiae data to database using this code:

```
void reader_On_Captured(CaptureResult capResult)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_sender.CheckCaptureResult(capResult)) return;

            fingerindex++;
            DataResult<Fmd> fmd = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromFid(capResult.Data, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI);

            SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "A fingerprint was captured.  \r\nCount:  " + fingerindex);
            // Get view bytes to create bitmap.
            foreach (Fid.Fiv fiv in capResult.Data.Views)
                {
                    //Ask user to press finger to get fingerprint
                    pbFingerprint1.Image = _sender.CreateBitmap(fiv.RawImage, fiv.Width, fiv.Height);
                    SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Now place the same finger on the reader.");
                }
            preEnrollmentFmd.Add(fmd.Data);

            if (fingerindex >= 4)
            {
                enrollmentFmd = Enrollment.CreateEnrollmentFmd(Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI, preEnrollmentFmd);

                if (enrollmentFmd.ResultCode == Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                {
                    SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "An enrollment fmd has successfully created.");
                    SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Click save to save your data..");

                    fmd1 = enrollmentFmd;

                    string empID = txtEmpID.Text.ToString();
                    Biometrics.updateFMDUserIDList(fmd1.Data, empID);

                    if (!CheckIfUserExists())
                    {
                        passCapturedFinger(Fmd.SerializeXml(fmd1.Data));
                        SaveEnrolledFmd(Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpID.Text), Fmd.SerializeXml(fmd1.Data));
                    }
                    fingerindex = 0;
                    return;
                }
                else if (enrollmentFmd.ResultCode == Constants.ResultCode.DP_ENROLLMENT_INVALID_SET)
                {
                    SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Enrollment was unsuccessful.  Please try again.");
                    preEnrollmentFmd.Clear();
                    fingerindex = 0;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

private void SaveEnrolledFmd(int userName, string xmlFMD1)
    {
        // Save user and his relative FMD into database
        try
        {
            if (db.openConnection())
            {
                string saveFmdScript = "insert into tblFingerprint(EmpID, FXml) values ('" + userName + "', '" + xmlFMD1 + "')";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(saveFmdScript, db.connect);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            db.closeConnection();
        }
        db.closeConnection();
    }
```

But for matching the fingerprint from database, I still don't know how I can make it simpler. I tried to use this code to match but it takes so much switch in order to match.

```
void reader_On_Captured(CaptureResult captureResult)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_sender.CheckCaptureResult(captureResult)) return;

            SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "A finger was captured");
            DataResult<Fmd> resultConversion = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromFid(captureResult.Data, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI);

            foreach (Fid.Fiv fiv in captureResult.Data.Views)
            {
                picBio.Image = _sender.CreateBitmap(fiv.RawImage, fiv.Width, fiv.Height);
            }

            if (resultConversion.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
            {
                _sender.Reset = true;
                throw new Exception(resultConversion.ResultCode.ToString());
            }

            anyFinger = resultConversion.Data;
            empIDs = Biometrics.GetAllUserNames;
            fmds = Biometrics.GetAllFmd1s;
            int thresholdScore = DPFJ_PROBABILITY_ONE * 1 / 100000;
            int countOf = 0;

            IdentifyResult identifyResult = Comparison.Identify(anyFinger, 0, fmds, thresholdScore, 1);

            if (identifyResult.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
            {
                _sender.Reset = true;
                throw new Exception(identifyResult.ResultCode.ToString());
            }

            //SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Identification resulted in the following number of matches: " + identifyResult.Indexes.Length.ToString());
            int a = 0;
            #region Match Finder
            for (i = 0; i < fmds.Length; i++)
            {
                countOf++;
                CompareResult compareResult = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmds[i], 0);
                if (compareResult.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                {
                    _sender.Reset = true;
                    throw new Exception(compareResult.ResultCode.ToString());
                }

                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Identification resulted with dissimilarity score of " + compareResult.Score.ToString());

                switch (countOf)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            if (txtString.Text != null)
                            {
                                fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            }
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
                        {
                            passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
                            selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
                            CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
                            if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                _sender.Reset = true;
                                throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
                                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        _sender.Reset = true;
                        throw new Exception(compareResult.ResultCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            #endregion
            if (identifyResult.Indexes.Length > 0)
            {
                loadTimein();
                loadName();
                loadPicture();
                //frmSelectJob = new frmSelectJob();
                //frmSelectJob._sender = this;
                //frmSelectJob.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint not registered.");
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, your fingerprint is not registered to database.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make this code simpler? Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only *need* three switch blocks here, with 11 cases:

```
case 1:
    if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
    {
        passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
        selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
        if (txtString.Text != null)
        {
            fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
        }
        CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
        if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
        {
            _sender.Reset = true;
            throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
            SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
        }
    }
    break;
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
case 10:
    if (compareResult.Score == 0 || compareResult.Score <= 100)
    {
        passCapturedFinger(countOf.ToString());
        selectFingerXml(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
        fmd1 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(txtString.Text);
        CompareResult compare = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fmd1, 0);
        if (compare.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
        {
            _sender.Reset = true;
            throw new Exception(compare.ResultCode.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            selectFingerCredentials(Convert.ToInt32(txtXml.Text));
            SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Fingerprint Matched on the count of " + countOf);
        }
    }
    break;
default:
    _sender.Reset = true;
    throw new Exception(compareResult.ResultCode.ToString());
```

You're *allowed* to have case-fallthrough in C# **if** that case has **no code** associated with it.

Even better: the only difference between `case 1` and the rest is that you check `txtString.Text != null` in `case 1`, apply that to the other cases and you can make it an `if`/`else`:

```
if (countOf >= 1 && countOf <= 10)
{
    // Code for case 1-10
}
else
{
    // Code for default
}
```

Why make it overly complex?

Besides that, why do you violate SRP so *drastically*? You should be breaking your code into methods with a single purpose/responsibility each, not creating one massive *super*-method.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and seems to be working fine. I am just new to C# and have a lot to learn. Your response is very much appreciated.